# How to find if the function exist in python

Tags: python-3.x

there are several ways to find the corresponding functions of on Object, the one I have been using often is 'dir':

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.gcf()
dir(fig)
```

Now suppose, that I have an idea how the function is called; for example, it’s `set_size***`. In this case, though, I am not completely sure if it’s `set_size_inches` or `set_size_inch`.

Is there any way that I could provide my partial piece of information to figure out the complete correct name of the function?

Something like:

```
hasattr(fig, set_size*)
```

Comment: How about using google and library documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all module's members like this

```
[fn for fn in fig if fn.startswith('set_size')]
```

So you can get module function

```
fn_name = [fn for fn in fig.__dict__.keys() if fn.startswith('set_size')][0]
fn = getattr(fig, fn_name)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, unfortunatley receiving following error: ``` ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-3d73c1b7c7c4> in <module>()
----> 1 fn_name = [fn for fn in fig.__dict__.keys() if fn.startswith('set_size')][0]
      2 fn = getattr(fig, fn_name)

IndexError: list index out of range ```

Comment: @Violet Most likely the module has no function with name set_size*. You can check all module function   print([fn for fn in fig ])

Comment: There is little tiny modification needed (dir(fig) instead of iterating over just fig) in your code, then it works like I wanted:     ```                                                        >>> [fn for fn in fig if fn.startswith('set_size')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Figure' object is not iterable
>>> [fn for fn in dir(fig) if fn.startswith('set_size')]
['set_size_inches']
  ```    thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module for it and filter through it but honestly, the best way is probably google or documentation

Comment: thanks for reply, the main idea was to find the maximum possible information being on the notebook itself and not using google/doc much..